# Mudar o select quando o input for preenchido

Tags: select

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se o campo "PANTONE" input for preenchido, o campo select "LINEATURA" é automaticamente setado em "52".

Em PHP ou JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, fiz um exemplo resolvendo o seu problema!!!
Utilizando apenas as funções javascript *getElementById* e *selectedIndex*.
Para testar localmente basta executar o seguinte código em um navegador, salve-o em um arquivo *.html* e execute em seu navegador.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h3>Pantone</h3> <input type="text" id="pantone" onkeyup="verificarSelect();"/>
<br><br>
<select id="lineatura">
  <option value="volvo">SELECIONE</option>
  <option value="volvo">52</option>
  <option value="saab">42</option>
  </select>


 <script> 
    function verificarSelect(){
    var lineatura = document.getElementById('lineatura');
    var pantone = document.getElementById('pantone');

        if(pantone.value != ""){ // Se o valor for preenchido, setar o SELECT para 52
             lineatura.selectedIndex = 1; //Indice da opção 52
        }
        if(pantone.value == ""){ // Caso esteja vazio, selecionar alguma opção
             lineatura.selectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }


 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Para testar remotamente use: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LgBBqx

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Muito legal a solução André! Recomendo colocar um snippet do seu código para que os usuários que visualizarem a sua resposta também possam testar e ver funcionando.

Comment: Valeu @JoãoPedroSchmitz!

Comment: PERFEITO ! Exatamente o que precisava.

Comment: Ótimo saber que serviu! Abraços @JúlioRicardo